# NKE Socket Filter failed to register

Tags: macos, sockets, kernel-extension

Im working in kext, For socket filtering when i use `sflt_register` it failed to load by saying.

`_sflt_register` symbol is unresolved for this kext. (`libkern/kext`) link error.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you run the `kextlibs` command on your kext? You're probably missing the BSD kpi from your list of dependencies in the Info.plist.